# Logging out from Evernote API in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, evernote

How can we logout from evernote account in iOS. I was not able to find any method for that.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> There is no explicit logout operation, simply delete the auth token that you have received as well as any cached username and password information.

http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/19575-how-to-logout-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Evernote SDK for iOS](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios/) logging out can be accomplished by using the following line of code:

```
[[EvernoteSession sharedSession] logout];
```

Behind the scenes calling logout method will just clear user account credentials from the store and keychain which essentially logs the user out.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work for me - the browser caching retains the username/password so it is bypassed on a return to login and goes straight to the authorisation page.